# WCF XMLserialization of nested composite objects

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization, object, composite

Hi I have a service contract and in its implementation I am trying to write the request parameters it receives in a text file. Here a composite object of 'TypeA a' is passed as a parameter.

```
        namespace WebService
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IRequestStatusChanged" here, you must also update the reference to "IRequestStatusChanged" in App.config.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRequestStatusChanged
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Input StatusChanged(Input In);

    }

    [Serializable] [DataContract]
    public class Input
    {
        [DataMember]
        RequestStatus RS = new RequestStatus();

    }

    [Serializable] [DataContract]
    public class RequestStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        RequestToken RT = new RequestToken();

        [DataMember]
        public String State

    }
    [Serializable] [DataContract]
    public class RequestToken
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id;
    }
}

Implementation of contract

namespace WebService
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "RequestStatusChanged" here, you must also update the reference to "RequestStatusChanged" in App.config.
    public class RequestStatusChanged : IRequestStatusChanged
    {
        public Input StatusChanged(Input In)
        {


           /* IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            Stream outfile = new FileStream(@"C:\test.txt", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Write);
            formatter.Serialize(outfile, In);
            outfile.Close(); */


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Input));
            TextWriter TW = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(TW, In);
            TW.Close();

            return In;
        }

    }
}
```

earlier I tried IFORMATTER to serialize the object and write it to text file but it is not human readable, so I tried xml serialization.

When I check the XML file written it only has tags for 'TypeA' object and does not write 'TypeB' and 'TypeC' objects to the file. I have marked all the classes as [Serializable] in the service contract. I want to write all the parameters received in the text or xml format to a file so that they are readable (kind of a log file).

Comment: When your client sends the TypeA object, does it set a value for TypeC of TypeB? The serializer may not be committing these to a file if they're all null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types 'TypeB' and 'TypeC' aren't written to the files because they're not necessary - when the serializer is serializing or deserializing an instance of TypeA, it knows that the type of the member 'b' is `TypeB`, so it doesn't write the type information. Do you need this information as well? Since you're serializing a `TypeA`, and you know that the field `b` is of type `TypeB`, you don't need that extra information in the log file.

In all serializers used by WCF, the only one which you can "force" the type to be written all the time is the JSON serializer - but then you'll get the result as JSON, not as XML - see below.

```
public class StackOverflow_6666697
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeA { [DataMember] public TypeB b = new TypeB(); }
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeB { [DataMember] public TypeC c = new TypeC(); }
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeC { [DataMember] public string S1; }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "  ",
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
        TypeA instance = new TypeA { b = new TypeB { c = new TypeC { S1 = "Hello world" } } };

        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(TypeA)).Serialize(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("XmlSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TypeA)).WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("DataContractSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new NetDataContractSerializer().WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("NetDataContractSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TypeA), null, 65536, false, null, true).WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("DataContractJsonSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Another option (which I really don't advise, as you'd be changing the logic of your system for the sake of logging) would be to declare the fields as `object`. This way, since the declared type is different than the actual one, the type information will be written out - see below.

```
public class StackOverflow_6666697
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeA { [DataMember] public object b = new TypeB(); }
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeB { [DataMember] public object c = new TypeC(); }
    [DataContract]
    public class TypeC { [DataMember] public string S1; }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "  ",
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
        TypeA instance = new TypeA { b = new TypeB { c = new TypeC { S1 = "Hello world" } } };

        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(TypeA), new Type[] { typeof(TypeB), typeof(TypeC) }).Serialize(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("XmlSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TypeA), new Type[] { typeof(TypeB), typeof(TypeC) }).WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("DataContractSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        new NetDataContractSerializer().WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("NetDataContractSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms.SetLength(0);
        w = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TypeA), new Type[] { typeof(TypeB), typeof(TypeC) }, 65536, false, null, true).WriteObject(w, instance);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("DataContractJsonSerializer:");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info..really helpful. The request is received in the XML format so I want to write it to a file in the XML or plain text format so that it is readable. Yes I need TypeB and TypeC object written as well. It would be great if I can find some way to write the whole composite object to a file.

Comment: Does the request contain the type information you want? If so, you can consider using a MessageInspector (IDispatchMessageInspector) to log the request at that point.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP's question about needing *type* information - only that the nested values aren't being written. That's because `XmlSerializer` won't touch non-public members.

Comment: I have already declared the members as public , sorry I missed it here. I guess according to above information XMLseralizer just wont serialze the nested objects. It will only serialize the single specified type of object.

Comment: @user832219, I'd suggest you to update the code in your post if you declared them as public. Can you clarify what you need? Do you need the *instances* of TypeB/TypeC to be serialized (if they're public, the XmlSerializer should do that), or do you need their *type names* to be serialized in addition to their instances?

Comment: I updated the code. Its the actual snippet I wrote. yes I need the instance of whole nested object of all three types to be serialized and written to a file.

Comment: I appreciate your help and time! got it.. I had to make the object instances public.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer` only serialises *public* members. None of the members in the `DataContract` types you've defined have any access specifiers, so they default to private.

However, you're using two different serialisation frameworks here - `DataContractSerializer` is implicitly used by WCF unless you tell it otherwise, and `XmlSerializer`. Why not just use `DataContractSerializer`, as you've got all the attributes it needs already in place for WCF's purposes?

```
var serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TypeA));
serialiser.WriteObject(xmlWriter, typeAObj);
```